# To match a perticular string in cinch bot

Tags: ruby, regex, cinch

Am trying to match a particular string in Cinch bot framework .

So my current code works fine but only fails if the string comes with some extra words .e.g

say am trying to match only "hello-1234" then it responds properly but if am putting like "common hello-1234 " or "hello-1234 closing" then the code fails.

Could anybody can guide my how i can get rid of this .

Code :

```
require 'cinch'
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/https'

class Jira
  include Cinch::Plugin

  listen_to :message


  def listen(m)

    rx = config.jira.regex
    if md = m.message.match(rx)
    url = "#{config.jira.url}#{m.message.upcase}"
      response = httpget url
      details = Nokogiri::HTML response
```

config.jira.regex = /\b(ora)-(\d{0,7})\b/i

with this regex its matching  ora-1234567. say i have "start ora-1234" or ora-1234 end" in above case how it should ignore the start and end and match only "ora-1234"

Comment: Seeing some of the relevant code would be very helpful, including the exception stack trace or unexpected output.

Comment: it *sounds* like you want it to match whether or not it is the whole string or a substring within a string, and it *sounds* like it's failing because your current regex is using anchor chars e.g. `^string$` but you need to post code if you want more than random guessing

Comment: @aliteralmind -updated thread.

Comment: I see some code, but I don't see what's *being* matched ("ora-1234"), nor the code that's actually trying to *do* the match (that uses `config.jira.regex`)...

Comment: your regex should match "common ora-1234 " or "ora-1234 closing" just fine.. but your regex *is* looking for a literal "ora" so your "hello-1234" example isn't going to match in *any* of your scenarios. Perhaps what you really want is `/\b(\w+)-(\d{0,7})\b/i`  ?

Comment: but to be clear, those `\b` things are word boundaries, so it will match if the string is at the beginning or end of the content or surrounded by non-word chars. But it's not going to match on for example (using your original regex with hardcoded "ora") "fooora-1234bar". `\b` is a word boundary assertion that looks for a change from a non-word char to a word char or visa versa.

Comment: @CrayonViolent How can i overcome this ? say starting ora-1234, so it should ignore the starting and only match ora-1234, or ora-1234 closed , and in this case it should match ora-1234 and ignore closed

Comment: @pradhans0906 I don't understand what you mean. What is your content vs. what you are trying to match? Are you trying to ensure that the *entire* content is *only* "ora-1234" or are you wanting to allow it to be matched as a substring within content but only at beginning or end of string or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *extract* the target from within the message, use this regex:

```
/ora-\d{0,7}/i
```

I looks like you're using ruby, so here's the code to get the target from a longer string:

```
code = m.message.match(/ora-\d{0,7}/i)[0]
```

Comment: How can i overcome this ? say starting ora-1234, so it should ignore the starting and only match ora-1234, or ora-1234 closed , and in this  case it should match ora-1234 and ignore closed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. With regex, the best way of describing the problem is to give examples of input that should match, and some examples of input that should *not* match. Chose your examples so they demonstrate the edge cases. Update your question to include these, then leave me a message here to let me know you've done it.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear or you .Updated the original question, can you please have a look and let me know if it make sense.

Comment: Is it that you want to *extract* `ora-nnnn` from the message?

Comment: see edited answer. if you're using ruby, please add that tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the portion of a message as a variable just do something like this:

```
listen: /(ora-\d{0,7})/i

def listen(m, jiraid)
  url = "#{config.jira.url}#{jiraid}"
  response = httpget url
  details = Nokogiri::HTML response
```

Any regex groups [the bits in ()'s] are passed to any relevant plugin methods as extra arguments.